# how to join 3 models to display data in a cgridview using yii

Tags: yii

i am newbie in yii framework. I have 3 tables table A,table B,table C. table A and table B are related with primary and foreign key relationship.same way table B and table C are linked with priamary and foreign key relationshiop..i want to display,filter data in cgridview of admin page..using a yii fra
    updated:
i have 3 models.subscriber.php,assignment.php,groups.php 
 i want to display attributes from 3 models and display them in cgridview of subscriber.php???

subscriber.php..........

```
    /**
     * This is the model class for table "users_phone_numbers".
     *
     * The followings are the available columns in table 'users_phone_numbers':
     * @property integer $id
     * @property string $name
     * @property string $phone_number
     * @property integer $created_user
     * @property string $created_date
     * @property integer $modified_user
     * @property string $modified_date
     * @property integer $status
     * @property string $message_type
     * @property string $birthdate
     * @property string $email
     *
     * The followings are the available model relations:
     * @property PhoneNumberGroupAssignment[] $phoneNumberGroupAssignments
     */
    class subscriber extends CActiveRecord
    {

        //public $group_search;      //for searching and displaying in cgridview
        /**
         * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
         * @param string $className active record class name.
         * @return subscriber the static model class
         */
        public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
        {
            return parent::model($className);
        }

        /**
         * @return string the associated database table name
         */
        public function tableName()
        {
            return 'users_phone_numbers';
        }

        /**
         * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
         */
        public function rules()
        {
            // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
            // will receive user inputs.
            return array(
                array('phone_number, created_user, created_date, birthdate, email', 'required'),
                array('created_user, modified_user, status', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
                array('name, phone_number', 'length', 'max'=>100),
                array('message_type', 'length', 'max'=>20),
                array('email', 'length', 'max'=>150),
                array('modified_date', 'safe'),  
                // The following rule is used by search().
                // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
                array('id, name, phone_number, created_user, created_date, modified_user, modified_date, status, message_type, birthdate, email ', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),//add above defined variable.
            );
        }

        /**
         * @return array relational rules.
         */
        public function relations()
        {
            // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
            // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
            return array(
                'phoneNumberGroupAssignments' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Assignment', 'phone_number_id'),
                //'postCount' => array(self::STAT, 'assignment', 'phone_number_id'),
            );
        }

        /**
         * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
         */
        public function attributeLabels()
        {
            return array(
                'id' => 'ID',
                'name' => 'Name',
                'phone_number' => 'Phone Number',
                'created_user' => 'Created User',
                'created_date' => 'Created Date',
                'modified_user' => 'Modified User',
                'modified_date' => 'Modified Date',
                'status' => 'Status',
                'message_type' => 'Message Type',
                'birthdate' => 'Birthdate',
                'email' => 'Email',
            );
        }

        /**
         * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
         * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models based on the search/filter conditions.
         */
        public function search()
        {
            // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
            // should not be searched.

            $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
            //$criteria->with = array( 'phoneNumberGroupAssignments' );   //new


            $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
            $criteria->compare('name',$this->name,true);
            $criteria->compare('phone_number',$this->phone_number,true);
            $criteria->compare('created_user',$this->created_user);
            $criteria->compare('created_date',$this->created_date,true);
            $criteria->compare('modified_user',$this->modified_user);
            $criteria->compare('modified_date',$this->modified_date,true);
            $criteria->compare('status',$this->status);
            $criteria->compare('message_type',$this->message_type,true);
            $criteria->compare('birthdate',$this->birthdate,true);
            $criteria->compare('email',$this->email,true);
            //$criteria->compare( 'phoneNumberGroupAssignments.group_id', $this->group_search, true );

            return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array('criteria'=>$criteria,
            /*'sort'=>array(
            'attributes'=>array(
                'group_search'=>array(
                    'asc'=>'phoneNumberGroupAssignments.group_id',
                    'desc'=>'phoneNumberGroupAssignments.group_id DESC',
                ),
                ),
                ),
                */

                    ));
        }
    }
```

2nd assignment.php

```
        /**
         * This is the model class for table "phone_number_group_assignment".
         *
         * The followings are the available columns in table 'phone_number_group_assignment':
         * @property integer $id
         * @property integer $phone_number_id
         * @property integer $group_id
         * @property integer $created_user
         * @property string $created_date
         * @property integer $modified_user
         * @property string $modified_date
         *
         * The followings are the available model relations:
         * @property UsersPhoneNumbers $phoneNumber
         */
        class assignment extends CActiveRecord
        {
            /**
             * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
             * @param string $className active record class name.
             * @return assignment the static model class
             */
            public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
            {
                return parent::model($className);
            }

            /**
             * @return string the associated database table name
             */
            public function tableName()
            {
                return 'phone_number_group_assignment';
            }

            /**
             * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
             */
            public function rules()
            {
                // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
                // will receive user inputs.
                return array(
                    array('phone_number_id, group_id, created_date', 'required'),
                    array('phone_number_id, group_id, created_user, modified_user', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
                    array('modified_date', 'safe'),
                    // The following rule is used by search().
                    // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
                    array('id, phone_number_id, group_id, created_user, created_date, modified_user, modified_date', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
                );
            }

            /**
             * @return array relational rules.
             */
            public function relations()
            {
                // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
                // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
                return array(
                    'phoneNumber' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Subscriber', 'phone_number_id'),
                );
            }

            /**
             * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
             */
            public function attributeLabels()
            {
                return array(
                    'id' => 'ID',
                    'phone_number_id' => 'Phone Number',
                    'group_id' => 'Group',
                    'created_user' => 'Created User',
                    'created_date' => 'Created Date',
                    'modified_user' => 'Modified User',
                    'modified_date' => 'Modified Date',
                );
            }

            /**
             * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
             * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models based on the search/filter conditions.
             */
            public function search()
            {
                // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
                // should not be searched.

                $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

                $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
                $criteria->compare('phone_number_id',$this->phone_number_id);
                $criteria->compare('group_id',$this->group_id);
                $criteria->compare('created_user',$this->created_user);
                $criteria->compare('created_date',$this->created_date,true);
                $criteria->compare('modified_user',$this->modified_user);
                $criteria->compare('modified_date',$this->modified_date,true);

                return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
                    'criteria'=>$criteria,
                ));
            }
        }
```

3rd one :
groups.php

```
      /**
       * This is the model class for table "client_groups".
       *
       * The followings are the available columns in table 'client_groups':
       * @property integer $id
       * @property integer $client_id
       * @property string $title
       * @property string $keywords
       * @property integer $status
       * @property integer $created_user
       * @property string $created_date
       * @property integer $modified_user
       * @property string $modified_date
       * @property integer $is_default
       * @property integer $is_special_group
       * @property string $back_office_no
       * @property string $special_group_sms_text
       * @property string $text_sms_office
       * @property string $day_delay_1
       * @property string $subscription_sms_1
       * @property string $day_delay_2
       * @property string $subscription_sms_2
       * @property string $day_delay_3
       * @property string $subscription_sms_3
       * @property string $campaign_sms
       * @property string $delay_time_1
       * @property string $delay_time_2
       * @property string $delay_time_3
       * @property integer $msg_counter
       * @property integer $msg_counter_start_num
       * @property integer $add_expiry
       * @property integer $add_days
       * @property integer $phone_number_id
       * @property integer $ar_type
       * @property string $email
       *
       * The followings are the available model relations:
       * @property ClientInformation $client
       */
      class Groups extends CActiveRecord
      {
          /**
           * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
           * @param string $className active record class name.
           * @return Groups the static model class
           */
          public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
          {
              return parent::model($className);
          }

          /**
           * @return string the associated database table name
           */
          public function tableName()
          {
              return 'client_groups';
          }

          /**
           * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
           */
          public function rules()
          {
              // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
              // will receive user inputs.
              return array(
                  array('client_id, created_user, created_date, msg_counter, add_expiry, add_days, phone_number_id, ar_type, email', 'required'),
                  array('client_id, status, created_user, modified_user, is_default, is_special_group, msg_counter, msg_counter_start_num, add_expiry, add_days, phone_number_id, ar_type', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
                  array('title', 'length', 'max'=>250),
                  array('keywords', 'length', 'max'=>255),
                  array('back_office_no', 'length', 'max'=>50),
                  array('day_delay_1, day_delay_2, day_delay_3', 'length', 'max'=>3),
                  array('subscription_sms_1, subscription_sms_2, subscription_sms_3, campaign_sms, email', 'length', 'max'=>200),
                  array('modified_date, special_group_sms_text, text_sms_office, delay_time_1, delay_time_2, delay_time_3', 'safe'),
                  // The following rule is used by search().
                  // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
                  array('id, client_id, title, keywords, status, created_user, created_date, modified_user, modified_date, is_default, is_special_group, back_office_no, special_group_sms_text, text_sms_office, day_delay_1, subscription_sms_1, day_delay_2, subscription_sms_2, day_delay_3, subscription_sms_3, campaign_sms, delay_time_1, delay_time_2, delay_time_3, msg_counter, msg_counter_start_num, add_expiry, add_days, phone_number_id, ar_type, email', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
              );
          }

          /**
           * @return array relational rules.
           */
          public function relations()
          {
              // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
              // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
              return array(
                  'client' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'ClientInformation', 'client_id'),
              );
          }

          /**
           * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
           */
          public function attributeLabels()
          {
              return array(
                  'id' => 'ID',
                  'client_id' => 'Client',
                  'title' => 'Title',
                  'keywords' => 'Keywords',
                  'status' => 'Status',
                  'created_user' => 'Created User',
                  'created_date' => 'Created Date',
                  'modified_user' => 'Modified User',
                  'modified_date' => 'Modified Date',
                  'is_default' => 'Is Default',
                  'is_special_group' => 'Is Special Group',
                  'back_office_no' => 'Back Office No',
                  'special_group_sms_text' => 'Special Group Sms Text',
                  'text_sms_office' => 'Text Sms Office',
                  'day_delay_1' => 'Day Delay 1',
                  'subscription_sms_1' => 'Subscription Sms 1',
                  'day_delay_2' => 'Day Delay 2',
                  'subscription_sms_2' => 'Subscription Sms 2',
                  'day_delay_3' => 'Day Delay 3',
                  'subscription_sms_3' => 'Subscription Sms 3',
                  'campaign_sms' => 'Campaign Sms',
                  'delay_time_1' => 'Delay Time 1',
                  'delay_time_2' => 'Delay Time 2',
                  'delay_time_3' => 'Delay Time 3',
                  'msg_counter' => 'Msg Counter',
                  'msg_counter_start_num' => 'Msg Counter Start Num',
                  'add_expiry' => 'Add Expiry',
                  'add_days' => 'Add Days',
                  'phone_number_id' => 'Phone Number',
                  'ar_type' => 'Ar Type',
                  'email' => 'Email',
              );
          }

          /**
           * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
           * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models based on the search/filter conditions.
           */
          public function search()
          {
              // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
              // should not be searched.

              $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

              $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
              $criteria->compare('client_id',$this->client_id);
              $criteria->compare('title',$this->title,true);
              $criteria->compare('keywords',$this->keywords,true);
              $criteria->compare('status',$this->status);
              $criteria->compare('created_user',$this->created_user);
              $criteria->compare('created_date',$this->created_date,true);
              $criteria->compare('modified_user',$this->modified_user);
              $criteria->compare('modified_date',$this->modified_date,true);
              $criteria->compare('is_default',$this->is_default);
              $criteria->compare('is_special_group',$this->is_special_group);
              $criteria->compare('back_office_no',$this->back_office_no,true);
              $criteria->compare('special_group_sms_text',$this->special_group_sms_text,true);
              $criteria->compare('text_sms_office',$this->text_sms_office,true);
              $criteria->compare('day_delay_1',$this->day_delay_1,true);
              $criteria->compare('subscription_sms_1',$this->subscription_sms_1,true);
              $criteria->compare('day_delay_2',$this->day_delay_2,true);
              $criteria->compare('subscription_sms_2',$this->subscription_sms_2,true);
              $criteria->compare('day_delay_3',$this->day_delay_3,true);
              $criteria->compare('subscription_sms_3',$this->subscription_sms_3,true);
              $criteria->compare('campaign_sms',$this->campaign_sms,true);
              $criteria->compare('delay_time_1',$this->delay_time_1,true);
              $criteria->compare('delay_time_2',$this->delay_time_2,true);
              $criteria->compare('delay_time_3',$this->delay_time_3,true);
              $criteria->compare('msg_counter',$this->msg_counter);
              $criteria->compare('msg_counter_start_num',$this->msg_counter_start_num);
              $criteria->compare('add_expiry',$this->add_expiry);
              $criteria->compare('add_days',$this->add_days);
              $criteria->compare('phone_number_id',$this->phone_number_id);
              $criteria->compare('ar_type',$this->ar_type);
              $criteria->compare('email',$this->email,true);

              return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
                  'criteria'=>$criteria,
              ));
          }
      }
```

current cgrid view is accessing data from two models,assignemnt and subscriber but not from groups. and it givers error rying to get property of non-object

C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\base\CComponent.php(607) : eval()'d code(1)
..so plz check this for 2 and then for 3 models? urgent help needed.thanks

Answer (score 2):

From the admin view for table A you should be able to access the other values by listing them like this in the column definition:

```
'columns'=>array(
    array('name'=>'column heading 1','value'=>'$data->modelB_nameinA->col_name1'),
    array('name'=>'column heading 2','value'=>'$data->modelB_nameinA->C->col_name2'),
```

For filtering on these values you need to be able to access them in the modelA->search() function. The simplest way I have found to do that is to explicitly set a public value in A for each col_name you want to display from B and C. You need to also include them in the safe search statement in modelA->rules() and for simplicity also in the modelA->attributeLabels(). You might also have to include C in the relations of A, so the modelA class would look something like this:

```
    class A extends CActiveRecord
{

    /**
     * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            ...
            // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('Col1_fromA, Col2_fromA, Col1_fromB, Col1_fromC', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }

    /**
    * Put here the names of the columns from B and C that you are wanting to filter on
    */
    public $Col1_fromB;
    public $Col1_fromC;

    /**
     * @return array relational rules.
     */
    public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            'modelB_nameinA'   => array(self::HAS_MANY,   'B',    'B_id'),
            'modelC_nameinA'    => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'C', array('C_id'=>'id'),'through'=>'B'),
        );
    }


    /**
     * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'Col1_fromA' => 'Fancy name for Col1_fromA',
            'Col2_fromA' => 'Fancy name for Col2_fromA',
            'Col1_fromB' => 'Fancy name for Col1_fromB',
            'Col1_fromC' => 'Fancy name for Col1_fromC',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
     * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models based on the search/filter conditions.
     */
    public function search()
    {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
        // this is so those two tables are included in the SQL generated:
        $criteria->with = array( 'B', 'C' ); 
        $criteria->together=true;

        $criteria->compare('Col1_fromA',$this->Col1_fromA,true);
        $criteria->compare('Col2_fromA',$this->Col2_fromA,true);
        $criteria->compare('modelB_nameinA.Col1', $this->Col1_fromB,true);
        $criteria->compare('modelC_nameinA.Col1', $this->Col1_fromC,true);


        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }
    ...
```

One advantage of this is that you can now use the Col1_fromB and Col1_fromC as the name value in the columns definition in cgridview and you will get the fancy names you entered in the definition of modelA as column headings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define relations in table A and B to get model C from table A.
Table A relations:

```
public function relations() {
    return array(
        'tableB'=>array(self::HAS_ONE, 'TableB', 'tablea_id'),
    );
}
```

Table B relations:

```
public function relations() {
    return array(
        'tableC'=>array(self::HAS_ONE, 'TableC', 'tableb_id'),
    );
}
```

So you can acces tableB and tableC model, related with your tableA:

```
$modelB = $tableA->tableB;
$modelC = $tableA->tableB->tableC;
```

You can read [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr) about relational active record.

In your controller action get the model:

```
public function actionGrid() {
    $model = new ModelA('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();          
    $this->render('view', array('model'=>$model));
}
```

And view code with CGridView:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter' => $model,
    'ajaxUpdate'=>false,
    'selectableRows'=>'10',
    'columns'=>array(
            array(
                    'id'=>'checkBoxId',
                    'class'=>'CCheckBoxColumn',
            ),
            array(
                'class'=>'CDataColumn',
                'name'=>'modelA_attrib1',
                'value'=>'$data->attrib1',
                'sortable'=>true,
                'filter'=>true,
            ),
            array(
                'class'=>'CDataColumn',
                'name'=>'modelB_attrib1',
                'value'=>'$data->modelB->attrib1',
                'sortable'=>true,
                'filter'=>true,
            ),
            array(
                'class'=>'CDataColumn',
                'name'=>'modelC_attrib1',
                'value'=>'$data->modelB->modelC->attrib1',
                'sortable'=>true,
                'filter'=>true,
            ),
 ...
```

**Update:**
If I properly understood, you have MANY_TO_MANY relation within your `users_phone_numbers` and `client_groups` tables (group could be related with many phone numbers, and number refer to many groups).
So `phone_number_group_assignment` (commonly referred to as `phone_number_group`) must contain two primary keys:

```
     * @property integer $phone_number_id
     * @property integer $group_id
```

And relations of `subscriber`:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'groups' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Groups', 'phone_number_group_assignment(phone_number_id, group_id)'),
    );
}
```

Relations for `groups`:

```
    public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'phone_numbers' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Subscriber', 'phone_number_group_assignment(group_id, phone_number_id)'),
        );
    }
```

So you can access groups from subscriber: `$subscriber->groups`

Comment: thankd driver_by, plz see my new updated question with code snippets of 3 models...thanks

Answer (score 0):

make a view in database and put all your needed columns after joins operations and then make the model.
I use this always

Answer (score 0):

As @user181452 said, create a View and then generate a model. Other way would be that in your target model, bind each new attribute with a public variable in the model

```
class NewModel {
   public $new_attribute;
}
```

Then you would be able to access to it from views. You have to chose the cleanest way for your project, 'cause create a view is better if you have a complex JOIN.